# Smarty template file (.tpl) is not loading PHP code

Tags: php, templates, smarty

I have a smarty template file and I want to include code from a php file. It simply doesn't work. Here's the sfunc.php in templates folder:

```
function BeautySweet (){
    echo 'Script works fine.';
}
?>
```

**Now here's the .tpl file code I added:**

```
{include_php 'templates/sfunc.php';}
{ BeautySweet ();}
```

I also tried:

```
{include_php 'sfunc.php';}
{ BeautySweet ();}
```

Still no luck.

Comment: What Smarty version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Smarty 3.1.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its

```
{include_php file="templates/sfunc.php"}
```

instead of

```
{include_php 'templates/sfunc.php';}
```

(Given that the path **templates/sfunc.php** is correct)

Comment: Ok, it works but there is an error `Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: {include_php} is deprecated, use SmartyBC class to enable`

Comment: I tried digging deep into smarty documentation but I just can't find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The use of php in smarty 3+ has been removed and for a good reason, templates are not supposed to have php code. You can use [SmartyBC](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/bc.tpl) for backwards compatibility of old templates, but if you're creating a new project that's a really bad idea as you will probably have problems in the future. Create a plugin or do the required operations in your php file and pass the result as a variable instead.